# Terraform - Az Cli - MSAL token error - User does not exist

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-ad-msal, azure-cli, terraform-provider-azure

since today I am experiencing an error concerning terraform initilization using Azure AD Authentication.

Terrform v1.2.2 
Az Cli v2.37.0

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    tenant_id            = "XXX"
    subscription_id      = "XXX"
    resource_group_name  = "XXX"
    storage_account_name = "XXX"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "devops.terraform.tfstate"
    use_azuread_auth     = true
  }
}
```

```
terraform init
> Error: obtaining Authorization Token from the Azure CLI: parsing json result from the Azure CLI: waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: User 'XXX' does not exist in MSAL token cache. Run `az login`.
```

Upon running `az login` or `az logout/az login`, the error remains.
Deleting MSAL token cache file or `az account clear` do not help, either.
I am using latest versions of terraform and az cli. I was using terraform v1.1.x before when I encountered the error but upgrading did not solve it, either.
Also, the user definetly exists in the msal_token_cache.json at `Account.username`.

Any suggestions?

Cheers,
AJ

**SOLVED:**  
After reinstalling az cli, the issue resolved. I think it is a problem with WSL2. If not both terraform and az cli are windows binaries (or both linux binaries), configuration is probably all over the place.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: have you tired checking whether the user changed the password by any chance.

Comment: `az ad signed-in-user show` try running this command to check if the user information is corrrect or not . Also check the VM time is correct or not as I believe you are running it on a devops agent .

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue. I did the following and the issue was resolved:

az account clear

The ran the az login command.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [AJQREA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19329272/ajqrea) sharing the solution. Posting it as an solution to help other community member who might encounter the same problem in future.

The error is due to you having changed the password of your Azure account and the access token stored on the disk becoming invalid.

Terraform internally is just calling [`az account get-access-token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-get-access-token) - as such you should be able to run the same command to see the error.

Solution : After reinstalling or upgrading the `azure-cli-iot-ext` extension, Terraform was able to retrieve the access token again with new updated password.

**Reference : https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3686**